# How to search in e-mail's body with PHP?

Tags: php, email, imap

I wondered how can I search for a particular word in all inbox e-mails with PHP IMAP? This search might be a regexp performed over the message's body...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following..

Connect to the the inbox:

```
$imap_stream = imap_open($host,$username,$pass);
$imap_obj = imap_check($imap_stream);
$numMsgs = $imap_obj->Nmsgs;
```

Check out the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php) for the format of $host etc.

Loop around each message:

```
while ($mailNumber<= $numMsgs) {
  $message  = imap_fetchbody ($imap_stream,$mailNumber,1);

  //Regex each message:
  if(preg_match($pattern, $string){
         imap_mail ($to,$subject,$message);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want forward a specific email, you could use [imap_mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail.php) to send it on. See above.

Comment: sounds useful! and if I want to forward an specific found mail to another e-mail address, would be possible?